# how to use navigation controller programaticaly?

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller

i have a button in viewcontroller which navigates to editPage viewcontrooler

i want to use pushNavigation

i did below code in button action method

```
 @IBAction func editBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editProfile") as! editProfile
        let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newViewController)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigation, animated: true)
 }
```

but when i click on button it dosent navigate

i dont have navigation controler in storyboard.......

i dont want to present view controler

Comment: you need to have the navigation controller embeded with the ViewController in which the editButton is placed. Please show the code where you  are navigating to this viewController

Comment: i have not embeded navigation control anywhere i want to do it programatically

Comment: you are using appDelegate or sceneDelegate to set root viewController ?

Comment: i am not using any of them

Comment: this is confusing , how compiler reaches to your view controller in which the edit button is added. you set it as initial View controller from storyboard?

Comment: Try to drag a UINavigationController in your storyboard then set root is your controller that need to make a push action to editProfile

Comment: look i have one view controller in that three button are there every three buttons have action to move on another controller i want to use navigation as pushviewcontrooler not present i dont want to embed navigation control in stroryboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are setting your viewController as initail View Controller from storyboard but do not embed this in navigation controller , either embed your viewController in navigationController and set this navigation controller as initialViewController or follow this approach as you don't want to do it from storyboard:

In SceneDelegate , write :

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

and then in this method :

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        //Setup user state
      
        if let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VIEW_CONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER") as? ViewController {
            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            window?.rootViewController = nav
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

for IOS < 13, in AppDelegate.swift :

```
var window : UIWindow?
    
    //MARK:- DID FINISH LAUNCHING WITH OPTIONS : CALLED EVERYTIME WHEN APPLICATION LAUNCHES
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VIEW_CONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER") as? ViewController {
                  let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                  window?.rootViewController = nav
                  window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
              }
       
        return true
    }
```

Comment: can i so thse insted appdelegate file?

Comment: yes , for IOS < 13.0 , do it in appDelegate file and use its didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: i have updated my answer for IOS version lower than 13. Please upvote if it helped you.